# Как вставить значения переменных JS в тело HTML не имея id тэгов, через сам HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

В JS определяются текстовые переменные. В HTML документе нужно вставлять их в произвольных местах как часть самого документа, так как это делается через innerHTML.

Примерно вот такого я хочу добиться
    `<h1><script>printRightHere("Hello world!")</script></h1>`

Без JQuery.

Comment: Может есть возможность пробежать весь HTML например регуляркой заменяя все включения с определенным форматом на нужные?

Comment: Ещё вариант это дать id тэгу script и искать этот тэг в вызываемой функции, но тогда функции придется передать и сам id. То есть такое кастыльное решение, id будет подряд и в тэге скрипта и в аргументе вызова функции внутри скрипта.

Comment: можете более подробно объяснить **что** именно вы хотите сделать, **как** использовать и **какой** ожидается конечный результат?

Comment: Более подробно. В HTML внутри `body` я пишу: `Привет %username%` и вот это `%username%` нужно заменить на значение переменной, причем на стороне клиента.

Comment: То есть хотите сделать свой шаблонизатор?

Comment: Да, так и есть. Только теперь я знаю как это называется. )

Comment: Чем-то не устраивают уже существующие?

Comment: Я не рассматривал их, ведь не знал что искать. Не думаю, что в моём случае могут понадобиться серьёзные шаблонизаторы, решение предложенное @рони по-моему очень лаконично.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

первый скрипт из примера ставить выше всех остальных, которые с текстом.

```html
<script>
  function printRightHere(text) {
    var script = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    script = script[script.length - 1];
    script.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(text), script)
  }
</script>
<h1><script>printRightHere("Hello world!")</script></h1> 
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<b>Quae contraria sunt his, malane?</b>
  <h1><script>printRightHere("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet")</script></h1> Ratio enim nostra consentit
</p>
```

Comment: @Grundy потому что весь смысл этого скрипта в том чтобы быть заменёным на текст. Дело в том, что при загрузке HTML могут быть определены некоторые переменные, значения которых и будут вставляться на практике.

Comment: @рони По-моему это гениальное решение. =)